# legend() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels', Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with a program. I tried to plot a legend using a dictionary with the colors of the departments, but when I run the program, always had the same error:

`legend() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'.`

In theory I always have this variable in my handles (like in this example http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles). This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)
dep_color = {'a':'red','b':'blue','c':'green'}
label = []
for dep in dep_color:
    P.append(mpatches.Patch(color=dep_color[dep], label=dep))
    label.append(dep)
label = tuple(label)
plt.legend(handles=P,labels = label,bbox_to_anchor=(0.,1.02,1.,.102), loc=3,ncol=3, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
```

EDIT: Corrected

Comment: Take a look at the docs: http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure (do a Ctrl+F and search for `legend`, it's far down there). The `labels` argument is required, meaning you need to a `labels = (...)` arg in your `fig.legend` call.

Comment: But the argument 'label' are in the handle.

Comment: That is true, but by the look of it `matplotlib` doesn't know to look there for labels. It wants them explicitly sent as an argument. Try something like `labels = tuple([p.label for p in P])` (This is mostly speculation; I've never worked with matplotlib)

Comment: I've just modified the code applying your idea and now the plot has a problem. It doesn't plot the legend.

Comment: what is `P` , can u include that in code

Comment: P is a ist where are the colors and the labels of the legend (the handles). Look at the example that I post before: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles

Comment: The difference between what you are calling and that example is that you are calling the actual method on the figure object, that example is calling the pyplot wrapper. They have different calling requirements.  If you change `fig.legend(` to `plt.legend(` it works (you can take out the labels keyword you put in).

Comment: Ok, I did it and works. Thanks